# Is there a way to log Cognito sign up errors on AWS panels?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have an Android application that uses the AWS Cognito API to sign up users.

Sometimes, the sign up process can fail (for example, if user enters a invalid password). In this case, a error message will be launched on the application.

But, eventually, I can't access the user to understand the error causes. So, I'm asking if there is a way to check failed sign up requests in some service panel provided by AWS Console. I tried CloudTrail, but it don't appear to have any register about those requests. Also, there is no trigger like "pos-signup" from where I can retrieve the return status from a Cognito operation (even, I have a pre-signup trigger that executes with no errors).

Can anyone help me with this issue? Thanks in advance!